# How to increase output current while maintaining low voltage through a ferrite transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, frequency, amperage, ferrite

I'm building a circuit to generate a 4600 Hz square wave signal and couple that signal to household 120 V, 60 Hz AC mains. This remotely turns on and off a receiver device plugged into an outlet in another room.

I found a circuit online using the IRS2153 half-bridge driver with an RC combo on pins 2-3 that can generate the frequency signal. The receiver device turns on when the 4600 Hz signal is present and turns off when the signal is not present on AC mains. I'm using a ferrite SMPS transformer for "T1" in the diagram. A 20 W adjustable buck converter is connected to the transformer primary side center tap currently set a 1.5 VDC. The remote device specifies that the frequency signal it needs can range from 0.5 to 1.5 V.

The receiver device has a 1 kΩ signal sensitivity trimpot resistor. It does respond to the circuit only when the trimpot is turned down to nearly 0 Ω. Anything above about 40 Ω causes the receiver to not respond to the signal generated from the circuit.

I assume the generated signal frequency is good but the power behind it is too weak, since the receiver only responds when trimpot resistance is at or near zero.

On the circuit in the diagram, how would I maintain the low 1.5 V signal voltage output while increasing the current of the generated signal into the AC mains?

Specs of the SMPS ferrite transformer I'm using:

- Primary max voltage: 5 V
- Primary #1: 142 μH inductance & 11 mΩ resistance
- Primary #2 values same as #1
- Secondary max voltage: 140 V
- Secondary side: 112.5 mH inductance and 2.2 Ω resistance

[image: Frequency Generator Circuit with SMPS Transformer]

[image: 4680Hz Receiver Device Circuit]

Comment: Receiver circuit appears to be missing. What makes you think that 4.2 kHz is high enough for this application? What convinces you that this type of circuit will work especially when mains AC has such a low impedance at this signalling frequency?

Comment: Wasting so much power to transfer one bit inside a household is very bad style.

Comment: The secondary only has to output a couple of volts, thus should have less turns than the primary.

Comment: Welcome! Some more background is needed. Is this some standard power line communication protocol to push 4.6 kHz signal on top of 60 Hz?

Comment: @winny - the receiver device just needs a square wave superimposed on the AC mains at 4600Hz to trigger a response in the receiver. No encoded data or special protocol involved, just a plain square wave. The receiver device in the second diagram filters out the frequency signal using (I think) an RC filter circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka - Added the receiver device diagram. Several variations of this receiving device were manufactured to work on different frequencies in the 2kHz-10kHz range. Mine is configured for 4.6kHz. I have frequency circuit & receiver device working as intended, but only with receiver device sensitivity trimpot turned to zero ohms. I want the frequency generator circuit to output a stronger signal at the same 1.5v voltage so that the receiver device's sensitivity can be decreased.

Comment: Interesting. Does it have a name? How long is it supposed to propagate in the grid?

Comment: When I was working in automotive industry I worked on a generator to simulate a test called "Bulk Current Injection". It basically injects varying amplitude high-frequency current into the device's supply line to test if the device's operation/functionality is affected. The approach was to make a high power oscillator, use a toroidal inductor as a load, and run the supply cables through the toroid for injection. It worked well. And one advantage is that it's contactless. Although the frequency was in MHz range and the voltage shape was not affected, still you might want to consider.

Comment: @winny - it just produces the square wave signal across the AC mains as long as the +12v DC side is powered. Once the 12v power is switched off, it stops producing the frequency signal.

Comment: I was referring to the standard or protocol.